# hosting images on image hosting websites

Tags: web-hosting, traffic

my website traffic has increased a lot and now in some cases has difficulties handling these users specially on busy hours. I want save some of the images on the website on image hostings so that they load from there just like the jquery that we load from code.jquery.com or code.google.com.

I wanted to know is it wise to do so? do you know any good websites with permanent image hosting? any suggestions?

Comment: Amazon, Rackspace, Cloudflare and many other web hosts provide this, the service you're looking for is a cdn 'content delivery networking' which are incredibly fast and cheap.